# find LCM of two numbers in cpp

Tags: c++

/*Here i wrote code for find LCM of two numbers but i don't know why it is not work for 9-10 digit numbers. like if i give input as 245 and 922222222 then it is not work and don't show the output.*/

//code is given below

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

long long product;

long long lcm(long long x,long long y){

    if(x>y)
        product=x;
    else
        product=y;

    while(1){
        if(product%x==0 && product%y==0){
            break;
        }
        product++;
    }

    return product;
}

int main(){
    cout<<lcm(245,922222222);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is formatted in such a way that at first I thought it was just random lines of gibberish.

Comment: Following on, do you know what output you should be expecting? It sounds like the program is just running for a long time.

Comment: Also, I'm almost sure that this *does* print something after waiting for eternity.

Comment: you only need `std::gcd`, no loops, `lcm(a,b) = a*b / gcd(a,b);`

Comment: If you're going to return `product` from your function, there's absolutely no point to it being a global variable.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine, it's just going to take a few years for it to finish.

You're wasting a lot of time checking numbers that can't possibly be the result.  `n % (n + 1)` can't possibly be `0` for any `n` other than `1`.  In general, `n % (n + m)` can only be `0` if `m` is a multiple of `n`.  That means you can add the greater of `x` and `y` to `product` each loop instead of just `1` and cut down on a ton of work:

```
long long lcm(long long x,long long y) {

    long long greater = std::max(x, y);
    long long product = greater;

    while(product % x != 0 || product % y != 0) {
        product += greater;
    }

    return product;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dee9f2e6b23a9aa)

Of course, even that is more work than you need, since `std::gcd` exists:

```
long long lcm(long long x, long long y) {
    return x / std::gcd(x, y) * y;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/135082c222b41d8a)

That may be violating the spirit of the assignment though.